# Aspboilerplate only partially work on IIS but fully working in IIS Express

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, entity-framework, iis, abp

My Aspboilerplate website working fine on visual studio debug but not on local IIS. After publishing to the IIS the site only loads partially.Have some angular errors.I think it have something to do with bundling scripts.I am not familiar with IIS and also angular stuck at this for 2 weeks.I don't know what I am missing between local IIS 10 and IIS Express vs19.

[image]

**Updated**
I have changed ScriptBundle to Bundle in BundleConfig.cs and some of the js errors are solved.But still having problems with angular,my current js console log is as follows

```
`js:14582 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] 
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/$injector/modulerr`
Uncaught (in promise) Xc
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
at quickviewSidebar
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).spectrum is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check your browser console for JavaScript errors.

Comment: What's `quickviewSidebar` and `spectrum`?

Comment: quickviewSidebar.js - [link](https://jsfiddle.net/ozasgpxv/)  and spectrum color picker v1.3.4 [link](https://github.com/bgrins/spectrum)

Comment: the question is why does it works on IIS Express but not on local iis10.

Comment: What's `content`?

Comment: var content = document.querySelector('.page-content'); and it is defined in layout.js [link](https://jsfiddle.net/9pm57q13/)

Comment: I don't see that line in your link. Is it `null`?

Comment: It is in application.js [link](https://jsfiddle.net/jq6ybw2s/) and here is full project link no offense [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rim-EC6T0O2UGzLzLqvYbwXewk6LDsrU)

Comment: Can you put it on GitHub?

Comment: what's wrong with google drive.I have trouble creating repo.

Comment: I am wary about downloading an unknown rar file, especially one that is 276 MB. The template at [aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template) is less 10 MB.

Comment: it is safe. Anyway I uploaded it to the office server IIS 8.5 win 2012 server and installed most of the .net packages it is working now. But it doesn't work when I published via web deploy and after deploy I debug it again on vs it works on IIS, weird.

Comment: So no more problem?

Comment: Today at office, I tried testing on another server and I think the problem is angular injector module error ,in angular version 1.4.6. I don't have this error on working host.